# Load the last 3 and every new child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

What would be the best way to get the 3 last messages and append/push all new messages into a array? Would the following be ok? What if I would like to use $firebaseArray ?

```
var messages = [];
ref.child('messages').limitToLast(3).on('child_added', function(snap){
  messages.push(snap.val());
});

var tempMessages = $firebaseArray(ref.child('messages').limitToLast(3));
messages.$loaded(function(data){
  messages = data;
})
```

Comment: The above will initially show the last 3 messages. Then when a newer message arrives, it will remove the oldest message and show the new message.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The first one will add the new messages to the latest 3.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that. Indeed: the first one will add more items as thy arrive.  `$firebaseArray` doesn't support this behavior out of the box, so you'll have to modify it (and stop it from removing items).

Answer (score 1):

What you secretly want is a **range query**.

You want to start at the last three and listen onwards. You can use the `.start()` function to create a range query. Once you know where to start the range you can start at the last 3 messages and get every one after that.

[**Here's a JSBin demo** of the last three messages, plus any newly added messages](http://jsbin.com/habobijera/edit?js,output).

**The problem is though you have to know what the 3rd to last key is first.**

To do that we'll do an initial query of the last three, get the 3rd to last key and then run our range query. This is best done with a `.once` function, because we only care to get the last three items one time.

```
function LimitMessagesArray(Ref, $q) {
  // return a function so we can alter the limit amount
  return function LimitMessagesArray(lastLimit) {
    var limitQuery = Ref.child('messages').limitToLast(lastLimit);
    // Since it's a one time read we'll use a promise
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // Reading only once is necessary
    limitQuery.once('value', function(snap) {
      var newMessages = [];
      // iterate through the snapshot and keep the key around
      snap.forEach(function(childSnap) {
        var newMessage = childSnap.val();
        newMessage.$key = childSnap.key();
        newMessages.push(newMessage);
      });
      // resolve the last 'N' messages
      deferred.resolve(newMessages);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
}
```

Now we have the last 'N' messages in an promise-fulfilled array. We want to take the **first key of the array** and use that to start the range query. To make this easier we'll create a factory a range of messages.

```
function StartAtMessagesArray(Ref, $firebaseArray) {
  return function StartAtMessagesArray(startingKey) {
    var rangeQuery = Ref.child('messages').orderByKey().startAt(startingKey);
    return $firebaseArray(rangeQuery);
  };
}
```

Once we have these two pieces we can use them together to listen to the last three messages plus all of the newly added ones.

```
function MyController($scope, limitMessages, startAtMessages, Ref) {
  var lastThreeMessages = limitMessages(3);
  // When the last three messages load get the first key
  lastThreeMessages.then(function(data) {
    var startingKey = data[0].$key;
    // Create the sync array of messages from the starting key
    $scope.messages = startAtMessages(startingKey);
  });
}
```

Comment: Well, kinda the correct answer. A good answer. But wondering, why would you use on 'value' instead of child_added ?

Comment: It's a once function which only can take a value event. Which makes sense because you're not going to get a stream of child added events one time. This is just to know where to start, after that we use firebaseArray, which under the hood wraps all the child events to synchronize the array.

Comment: Ok. Another thing, you are never using LimitMessagesArray?

Comment: I am, it's registered name with Angular is "limitMessages". It's on the first line of the controller. Look at the JSBin I made for you. Is there any other criteria this answer is missing to be accepted?

Comment: I actually think it's a rather bad way of solving the problem. Loading 3 messages first and then load them again + new.. Really weird way of solving the problem.

Comment: You need to know the 3rd to last key to start syncing from that point. That requires getting the 3rd to last object. This is not a common use case so it requires an uncommon solution.

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Comment: I came up with an own solution but havne't had time to post it.

Answer (score -1):

Inject `firebaseArray()` to your controller and define the reference you want the array for. For example:

```js
app.controller("Ctrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray",
  function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var desiredRef = new Firebase("URL of your app ");
```

Now create an array for data for `firebaseArray(desiredRef)` -

```js
$scope.tempMessages = $firebaseArray(desiredRef);
```

Through the same `firebaseArray()` service you can use `query()` for last three messages -

```js
var query = desiredRef.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(3);

//create another array for last(3)
$scope.lastThree = firebaseArray(query);
```

[Official documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray) quotes:

> This is a PSEUDO READ-ONLY ARRAY suitable for use in directives like
>   ng-repeat and with Angular filters (which expect an array).

Another note, with this service `push()`, `splice()` and other functions will make the array unable to be updated. So use specific APIs as suggested in the documentation. For instance, $add instead of `push()`.

Further reference and example [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html).

Comment: That will only show the last 3. I want the last 3, and when new messages are added, the first 3 plus the new ones should be shown.